# Can't update to numpy 1.13 with anaconda?

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, conda

PyPI has numpy 1.13.3 packages for a month now https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy

Anaconda cloud claims to have 1.13 https://anaconda.org/anaconda/numpy

But I just get 1.11.3-py35_0 when I use `conda update numpy`

[image]

My environment: Windows 7 64 bit python 3.5

Comment: Perhaps there is a conflict with your existing packages.  Try creating a new environment `conda create -n my_env numpy`

Comment: You can always just get rid of blaze if you don't need it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could try to install a specific NumPy version. In your case you could use:

```
$ conda install numpy=1.13
```

In case of conflicts it will show the conflicting packages.

For example:

```
$ conda install numpy=1.14

Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - blaze -> numba -> numpy[version='>=1.13,<1.14.0a0']
  - numpy=1.14
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

In this case `blaze` and `numba` prevent NumPy from upgrading.

Comment: yes, `basemap` was the problem, removed it and numpy 1.13.1 installs fine

Comment: Does there exist a similar command that targets the most recent version?

Comment: @TomNorway There's `conda install numpy` or `conda update numpy` which should install the newest (possible) version of numpy (from the available channels).

Comment: @MSeifert, please see the screenshot in the original post. `conda update numpy` doesn't do this, and neither does `conda install numpy`, at least for me. I had to specifically target `conda install numpy=1.17` yesterday to upgrade from 1.15. The commands are perhaps *supposed* to do this, but they appear not to.

Comment: @TomNorway Okay, then I misunderstood your comment. As far as I know there's no "version" that resolves to the latest version of a package.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem and none of them worked!

So I solved it using command:

```
pip install --upgrade numpy
```

Then, when I `ls` to my site-packages dir, I see it's updated to 1.14.0.

Comment: generally speaking, a bad idea to upgrade with pip in a conda environment

Comment: Why would that be?

Comment: You should try to install or upgrade everything either using pip or conda. Use conda if you are in Anaconda. Mixing those two might lead to backend errors. Keep environments also small on a project-basis.